# Como posso fazer para proteger um arquivo js?

Tags: javascript

Bom, a minha dúvida é bem simples, pretendo proteger de alguma forma um arquivo .js, de forma a que ninguém consiga ver o meu código.

Isso é possível de se fazer? Ou seja pretendo que nínguem tenha possiblidade e consiga ver o meu código.

Como poderei-o fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: Nope, a não ser minificar o código, que dificulta em muito a leitura

Comment: Código javascript no navegador sempre será visível, afinal o navegador precisa ler o arquivo pra ele funcionar. O máximo que voce pode fazer é minificar, como o Marcelo disse. Mal lhe pergunte, pra que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: O JavaScript que é interpretado pelo browser. Precisa ser "visto" pelo browser. E se o browser "vê". Qualquer pessoa poderá ver.

Comment: Pois, têm razão, de facto não é possivel esconder.